# Samsung S6 Webview css animations issue

Tags: cordova, css-animations, samsung-mobile

I'm working on application written in cordova/phonegap.
Now i have some strange issue - in Samsung s6 css animation does not work properly.
For example - i have a spinner animated with css.
Every time when launching application spinner doesn't want to hide.
I also hide some element using css animation.
 And after launching application this element doesn't slide.
What's strange these bugs occurs only on first application launching, every second time when css animation is applied it works.
Also simple touching the screen makes animation starting to work.

Version of Android is 5.1.1, webview is the newest 46.0.2490.
I'm not quite sure but assume that this bug occurs after WebView update from Google Play.

I feel powerless :(.
And my question is - where should i report that issue?
For any other device than S6 bugs don't occur, so Google Play is not proper place i suppose.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

We have the exact same issue with CSS animations in our Cordova-app on Samsung S6 5.1.1 webview. We noticed it first with our spinner, but it seems to impact all kinds of CSS animations.

This seems to be a bug in the Android System Webview version 46.0.2490.76.
Everything works fine when downgrading to the previous version, and it also works fine when we install a later version of the Webview manually (not yet available in Google play).

Until a new version is in place we have found a hacky workaround that seems to work fine for now.

From JS we create a fake touch-event, typically in our spinner.stop() function, or similar:

```
        
            if (Modernizr.touch) {
                var e = document.createEvent('TouchEvent');
                e.initTouchEvent();
            }
```

This have the same effect as when the user swipes or taps the screen, and the screen repaints.

Use modernizr to check if touch events are available (or implement your own check) to avoid error messages on non-touch devices such as a desktop.

I hope this can be of help until the webview get's updated in Google Play.